# C++: why is vector implementation not yielding comma-delimited values?

Tags: c++

I have a `database.txt` file with comma-separated values:

```
Name,ID,Year,Gender
```

I would like to extract each of these elements.

I've started with this code (I've already looked at all the other similar questions and implemented what they've suggested), but it's not printing each piece:

```
// reading a text file
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  string line;
  ifstream myfile ("database.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {
      std::string str = line;
      std::vector<int> vect;

      std::stringstream ss(str);

      int i;

      while (ss >> i)
      {
        vect.push_back(i);

        if (ss.peek() == ',')
            ss.ignore();
      }

      for (i=0; i< vect.size(); i++)
        std::cout << vect.at(i)<<std::endl;
        //cout << line << '\n';
      }

    myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

  return 0;
}
```

How can I modify it to be able to extract each value: name, ID, year, and gender? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is unlikely to have anything to do with the vector implementation.

Comment: Did you try single-stepping through the code with your debugger to see what it actually does, instead of what you want it to do?

Comment: This will work if this line std::string str = line; is replaced with std::string str = "a,b,c,d", meaning it will print the a, b, c,d, which makes me think it has to do with the formatting of line. I just don't know what the problem with line could be? It is string format

Comment: better to first split line by ',' and then push back each to vector.

Comment: Why are you reading int values from the stream and putting them into a vector that holds ints?  If your lines contain names and genders then wouldn't you want to read strings from the stream instead of int values?

Comment: Just debug the program or do some cout prints and you will quickly find the issue.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah that could be it, but if the int was significant, why did this work with "a,b,c,d"?

Comment: Use `strtok(string, char)` to parse the csv.

Comment: As it has been already  mentioned the vector implementation does not have anything to do with CSV or other formats in particular. You could have a look on regex library or one of the libraries that work with CSV formats. Regex library is a bit tricky but using it would solve the problem.

Comment: It was in fact that I had to use vector<string> format, which @aminsaffar helped with below.

Comment: Also, thanks @jerryjeremiah, I was wrong about it being able to print "a,b,c,d", it was actually "1,2,3,4"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function to split each line:

```
vector<string> split(const string &s, char delim) {
    stringstream ss(s);
    string item;
    vector<string> tokens;
    while (getline(ss, item, delim)) {
        tokens.push_back(item);
    }
    return tokens;
}
```

and your code be like:

```
// reading a text file
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  string line;
  ifstream myfile ("database.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {
      std::string str = line;
      std::vector<string> vect;

      vect = split(str, ',') ;

      for (int i=0; i< vect.size(); i++)
        std::cout << vect.at(i)<<std::endl;
        //cout << line << '\n';
      }

    myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That worked! thanks a lot @amin saffar, though I was wrong that vector<int> worked, it should have been vector<string>, and int was not declared so i just edited your answer to reflect those changes, thank you!

Comment: The above works good; but it doesn't abstract the part of reading the file from within the function to just parse a string of text. Parsing an actual string that is read in from a file should be independent of the actual reading in a line of string from the file.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of a utility function and a data structure you can simplify this quite easily.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<std::string> splitString( const std::string& stringToSplit, const std::string& delimiter, const bool keepEmpty ) {
    std::vector<std::string> results;
    if ( delimiter.empty() {
        results.push_back( stringToSplit );
        return results;
    }

    std::string::const_iterator itSubStrStart = stringToSplit.begin(), itSubStrEnd;
    while( true ) {
        itSubStrEnd = std::search( itSubStrStart, stringToSplit.end(), delimiter.begin(), delimiter.end() );
        std::string temp( itSubStrStart, itSubStrEnd );

        if ( keepEmpty || !temp.empty() ) 
            results.push_back( temp );

        if ( itSubStrEnd == stringToSplit.end() )
            break;

        itSubStrStart = itSubStrEnd + delimiter.size();
    }
    return results;
}

struct DataEntry {
    std::string name;
    unsigned id;
    unsigned year;
    std::string gender;
};

int main() {
    std::string line;
    std::fstream file;

    file.open( "database.txt" );

    std::vector<DataEntry> entries;
    std::vector<std::string> elements;

    while( file >> line ) {
        elements = splitString( line, "," );
        DataEntry entry;
        entry.name = elements[0];
        entry.id   = std::stoul( elements[1] );
        entry.year = std::stoul( elements[2] );
        entry.gender = elements[3];
        entries.push_back( entry );
    }

    file.close();

    for ( auto& e : entries ) {
        std::cout << e.name << " " << e.id << " "
                 << e.year << " " << e.gender << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << "\nPress any key and enter to quit.\n";
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

*`database.txt`*

```
John,12345,2010,M
Jane,54321,2012,F
```

*`output`*

```
John 12345 2010 M
Jane 54321 2012 F
```

This makes life it a lot easier just by reading in a single line first; then parsing that line of text and from there doing what you will with that data; either storing it to a struct, printing it, manipulating it etc.

*`Edit`*

You need to be aware of the fact that when reading in lines of text, and parsing them if you have something like this in your text file:

```
John Doe,12345,2010,M
```

It will not give you what you would expect. I'll leave that for you to figure out.